# How to remove know which file CSS is coming from when viewing compiled CSS?

Tags: css, sass

I am still getiing used to SCSS's 7-1 architecture. I can do `control+f` and find a particular class in my CSS file but sometimes I forget where it is coming from as I have multiple SCSS file following the 7-1 architecture.

Is there a way where I can locate which SCSS file the compiled CSS is coming from?

I am using Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sourcemaps and then the developer tools inside your browser to see where things actually came from.

See [this link](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/using-source-maps-with-sass)